# compare two columns in a excel using pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have data with about 3 different columns in excel.

```
    COLUMN A = Product name_1
    Column B = type
    column C = PRODUCT NAME_2 .
```

I wanted to check the names in column C against column A and if it matches, then extract the corresponding column B value.
Main excel sheet:

```
| column a | column b |column c|
| -------- | ---------|--------|
| apple    | 1        |  apple |
| microsoft| 0        |cognizant|
|google    |2         |amazon  |
|cognizant |0         |
|amazon    |1         |
```

and expected output as below:

```
    | column A | COLUMN b |
    | -------- | -------- |
    | apple    |  1       |
    | cognizant|  0       |
    |amazon    |  1       |
```

Can anyone suggest a function of code  in which I can do this without actually having to go through all of them row by row?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use [`df.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html):

```
In [1668]: df[df['column a'].isin(df['column c'])][['column a', 'column b']]
Out[1668]: 
    column_a  column_b
0      apple         1
3  cognizant         0
4     amazon         1
```